# How to use busco installed through conda?

Tags: software-installation, conda, busco

I have installed [busco](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/busco) on my Mac computer using `conda install --channel bioconda busco=3.0.2` into an environment called `busco3_0_2`. However, when I type `busco`, the command is not found.

Anyone knows what the name of the binary is? Usually when I install something with conda, the name of the command is the same as the name of the package. In this case, it does not seem to be so.

Note that the package installation finished successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [README](https://gitlab.com/ezlab/busco), it looks like the command-line entry point is not `busco` but `run_BUSCO.py`. This seems to agree with the [bioconda recipe](https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/blob/master/recipes/busco/meta.yaml), where `run_BUSCO.py` and `run_busco` are listed among the commands.

Comment: Cheers. I found `run_BUSCO.py` and `run_busco` in `~/anaconda/envs/busco3_0_2/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

[The new version of busco (v4)](https://busco.ezlab.org/busco_userguide.html#conda-package) has the user entry point called `busco` (it's still a python script). BUSCO v4 is [available at conda](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/busco), note it's a very fresh update.